# How do I convert a 4x3 grid to a 3x4 gird when I reach a certain media query?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a responsive grid.  The grid starts out as a 4x3, when I reach 720px, I want it to be a 3x4 grid.  I'm using bootstrap 3 (can't use bootstrap 4 for this project).  Now I'm able to do this using javascript, but I would like to do this with pure html and css.

Going from...

`A  B  C  D
 E  F  G  H
 I  J  K  L`

to...  @media only screen and (min-width: 720px)

`A  B  C
 D  E  F
 G  H  I
 J  K  L`

I realize you need rows in between, which is the reason I added it dynamically using javascript.  When it is there statically, I couldn't figure out how to do this.

```js
function gridDivideBy(divideNum) {

  $('.myClass').contents().unwrap();
  var $square = $(".square");

  for (let i = 0; i < $square.length; i += divideNum) {
    // Create dynamic div
    let $div = $("<div/>", {
      class: 'myClass row'
    });
    // Wrap all the boxes inside a row and div with myClass
    $square.slice(i, i + divideNum).wrapAll($div);
  }
}

function myFunc(x) {
  if (x.matches) {
    gridDivideBy(4);
  } else {
    gridDivideBy(3);
  }
}


var x = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 720px)")
myFunc(x);
x.addListener(myFunc);
```

```css
.square {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #eee;
  flex: 1;
}

.myClass {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 4px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container" id="square-wrapper">
  <div class="col-md-3 square">A</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">B</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">C</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">D</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">E</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">F</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">G</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">H</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">I</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">J</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">K</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 square">L</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding class `col-sm-4` along with `col-md-3`?

Comment: That gives me my 3x4 and 2x6 and 1x12, but not my 4x3 which is what I want to start with, but thanks, I'm just not good with grids.

Comment: You can use display:flex on the container, and then use width of 25% on the .square,  and then a media query for <750px  changing width to 33%, or grid, and thengrid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);

Answer (score 0):

Try to use other option **why?**

Because Bootstrap 3 use as first breakpoint the size of 768px

> Extra small devices Phones **(<768px)**

But, if you are really want to use bootstrap, this is your solution (I think...)

```
$(window).on("load, resize", function () {
    var viewportWidth = $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth > 720) {
            $(".col-xs-3").removeClass("col-xs-3").addClass("col-xs-4");
    }
        else{
            $(".col-xs-4").removeClass("col-xs-4").addClass("col-xs-3");
        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar w media queries, then you should be able to adjust your grid, using - I imagine - grid-template-rows and grid-template-columns.

```
@media screen and (max-width:720px) {
    .grid-container {
                grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}
```

Let me know if it helps. Thank you and good luck.